# Replay a video when it is finished and a replay icon is shown to be clicked by a user

Tags: flutter, dart

Edit: I just started studying Flutter and I still have a lot to learn. For now, I had a hard time looking for ways to replay a video. My goal is to replay a video when it is finished and a replay icon is shown for a user to click. These are the only packages I imported.

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

```
 Widget _buildVideoPlay() {
    return Center(
      child: _controller.value.initialized ? _VideoStack() : Container(),
    );
  }

 Widget _VideoStack() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        _VideoCore(),
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? _controller.initialize() : _controller.pause()
        }),
          child: Center(
            child: _controller.value.isPlaying
                ? Icon(Icons.pause, color: Colors.blue, size: 30.0)
                : Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.blue, size: 30.0),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _VideoCore() {
    return Container(
      child: Center(
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
          child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, set the finishedPlaying to be **true** if the duration of
the current position is equal to the duration of the video. Then use this boolean to show the Replay Button.

```dart
 bool finishedPlaying = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller.addListener(() {
    setState(() {
        });
      if (_controller.value.duration == _controller.value.position) {
        setState(() {
          finishedPlaying = true;
        });
        
      }
    });
  }
```

```dart
FlatButton(
          onPressed: () => setState(() {
                if (finishedPlaying) {
                  _controller.play(); // Replay the video
                } else {
                  _controller.value.isPlaying
                      ? _controller.play()
                      : _controller.pause();
                }
              }),
          child: Center(
              child: finishedPlaying
                  ? Icon(Icons.replay, color: Colors.blue, size: 30.0)
                  : (_controller.value.isPlaying
                      ? Icon(Icons.pause, color: Colors.blue, size: 30.0)
                      : Icon(Icons.play_arrow,
                          color: Colors.blue, size: 30.0)))),
```

Comment: Hi @sleepingkit. I tried it but it won't work. I already have this in my code where the video is initialized before pressing the play button.
` @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.network(url)
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        setState(() {});
      });
      
  }`

Comment: @NoobDev What is your situation right now , show the pause icon all the time, and the play-arrow icon not shown when the video is finished?

Comment: They are both working well. I can pause and play the video right now. My goal is when the video is finished, a replay icon will appear and when clicked, the video will play again.

Comment: @NoobDev oh I see, I have updated the answer, see if this helps you

Comment: Thank you! 
Shouldn't I change something in my Widget _VideoStack?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220075/discussion-between-noobdev-and-sleepingkit).

Answer (score 0):

i dont what you mean by reply is it like looping? you can try this

```
IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.loop,
                          color: _controller.value.isLooping
                              ? Colors.green
                              : Colors.black,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          _controller.setLooping(!_controller.value.isLooping);
                        })
```

Comment: My goal is to use the Icon(Icons.replay) :D

Answer (score 0):

```
bool isPlay = false;
bool finishedPlaying = false;

@override
void initState() {
super.initState();
videoPlayerController.addListener(() {
  setState(() {
  });
  if (videoPlayerController.value.duration == videoPlayerController.value.position) {
    setState(() {
      isPlay = false;
      finishedPlaying = true;
    });
  } else {
    setState(() {
      finishedPlaying = false;
    });
  }
});
```

}

```
Stack(
    children: [
      CachedVideoPlayer(videoPlayerController),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            if (finishedPlaying) {
              videoPlayerController.seekTo(Duration.zero);
              videoPlayerController.play(); // Replay the video
            }
            if (isPlay) {
              videoPlayerController.pause();
            } else {
              videoPlayerController.play();
            }
            setState(() {
              isPlay = !isPlay;
            });
          },
          icon: Icon(
            finishedPlaying
                ? Icons.replay
                : isPlay
                    ? Icons.pause_circle
                    : Icons.play_circle,
            size: 30,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```